# How to run automated Selenium test with Headless Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

All automated test which currently runs on Selenium webdriver, is there any way to run all of them with new Headless chrome?

Comment: My believe that Chrome team is still working on chromium- headless Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible with Chrome V60+. Add these 2 `chromeOption`s and you're all set:

```js
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can  run all of them with new Headless chrome. You need  to use chrome version 59  and add two chromeOptions to use headless chrome in selenium

Here is the code

https://www.automation99.com/2017/07/how-to-use-chrome-headless-using.html